# What is this M01PTH I see referenced on schematics?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, schematics

What is this part "M01PTH"?

I'm interested in building this "BBQ Temp Controller" Arduino-based project here:
http://hruska.us/tempmon/

One component involved is a 12v blower.  In looking at the schematic for the above link, I see that the positive for the blower is connected to something that says "M01PTH" above the designation "12V".  I cannot find any parts online that correspond to "M01PTH".

I see the same reference to "M01PTH" on a couple other schematics for power supply stuff as well, for example here:
http://www.schmalzhaus.com/UBW32/EE/v26/UBW32_MX795_v26_sch.pdf
and here:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Practical-DACs/step4/Build-It/

but I have no idea what this is.

Does anyone know what this is or means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the [EAGLE](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/) part designator for a single pin through hole header.